# How to read file from phone's internal memory in android?

Tags: android, memory, readfile

I have downloaded a file from `HttpConnection` using the `FileOutputStream` in android and now its being written in phone's internal memory on path as i found it in `File Explorer`

`/data/data/com.example.packagename/files/123.ics`

Now, I want to open & read the file content from phone's internal memory to UI. I tried to do it by using the `FileInputStream`, I have given just filename with extension to open it but I am not sure how to mention the file path for file in internal memory,as it forces the application to close.

Any suggestions?

---

This is what I am doing:

```
try
{               
  FileInputStream fileIn;       
  fileIn = openFileInput("123.ics");
  InputStream in = null;
  EditText Userid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user_id);
  byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
  int len = 0;
  while ( (len = in.read(buffer)) > 0 )         
  {     
     Userid.setText(fileIn.read(buffer, 0, len));
  }                    
  fileIn.close();                       
} catch (FileNotFoundException e)
{
   e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (IOException e)
{   
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: @rob where are you initializing InputStream? as from your code I can see that it is set to null.

Comment: you should probably save to external memory so you dont cause the user to run out of space and you need the permission to do so.

Answer (score 6):

```
String filePath = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();//returns current directory.
File file = new File(filePath, fileName);

Similar post here
```

[read file from phone memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654828/read-text-file-from-phone-memory-in-android)

Answer (score 4):

If the file is where you say it is, and your application is `com.example.packagename`, then calling `openFileInput("123.ics");` will return you a `FileInputStream` on the file in question.

Or, call `getFilesDir()` to get a `File` object pointing to `/data/data/com.example.packagename/files`, and work from there.

Comment: @rob, edit your original question to add this info, instead of posting it in comments.  Also, add your stacktrace.

Comment: @mbaird, How can i add stacktrace?

Comment: Why there is a silence, i am stuck in it. any suggestions?

Answer (score -2):

I am using this code to open file in internal storage. i think i could help.

```
File str = new File("/data/data/com.xlabz.FlagTest/files/","hello_file.xml");
```

Comment: different phones use different areas for storage. you should use the apis to determine the correct location. search data storage.