# read text file from phone memory in android

Tags: android

I just wanna create a text file into phone memory and have to read its content to display.Now i created a text file.But its not present in the path data/data/package-name/file name.txt & it didn't display the content on emulator.

My code is..

```
public class PhonememAct extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = openFileOutput("Test.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            fos.write("Hai..".getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fis = openFileInput("Test.txt");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        int c;

        try {
            while((c=fis.read())!=-1)
                    {
                        tv.setText(c);
                        setContentView(tv);

                        //k += (char)c;
                    }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

            try {
                fis.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


    }
}
```

Thanks in adv.

Comment: You also can put one try block and catch different exceptions. This makes the code more readable ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to use input/output streams if you are simply trying to write/read text.

Use FileWriter to write text to a file and BufferedReader to read text from a file - it's much simpler. This works perfectly...

```
try {
    File myDir = new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath());
    String s = "";

    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(myDir + "/Test.txt");
    fw.write("Hello World");
    fw.close();

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(myDir + "/Test.txt"));
    s = br.readLine();

    // Set TextView text here using tv.setText(s);

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I tried with your example.Text file is created well.But when i tried to run the program,I got error as "The Process stopped unexpectedly".            My logcat says..01-11 14:24:05.253: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25814): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
01-11 14:24:05.263: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25814):

Comment: @Sudhakar: I meant to mention that you can't use "setContentView(tv);" like that. You should have an XML layout file such as main.xml with your TextView in it and you should call "setContentView(R.layout.main);" immediately after you call "super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)". Don't set your content view to 'tv'.

Comment: Great!Finally i got.Thanks Mr.Squonk.

Answer (score 1):

```
    //Find the directory for the SD Card using the API
    //*Don't* hardcode "/sdcard"
    File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    //Get the text file
    File file = new File(sdcard,"file.txt");

    //Read text from file
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

    try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    text.append(line);
    text.append('\n');
    }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
    //You'll need to add proper error handling here
    }

    //Find the view by its id
    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view);

    //Set the text
    tv.setText(text);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//To read file from internal phone memory
//get your application context:
Context context = getApplicationContext(); 

filePath = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
File file = new File(filePath, fileName);
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));   
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        text.append(line);
        text.append('\n');
    }
}
catch (IOException e) {

}
return text.toString(); //the output text from file.
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be an answer to your question.
I think, you need to use the try-catch correctly.
Imagine `openFileInput()` call fails, and next you are calling `fos.write()` and `fos.close()` on a null object.

Same thing is seen later in `fis.read()` and `fis.close()`.

You need to include `openFileInput()`, `fos.write()` and `fos.close()` in one single try-catch block. Similar change is required for '`fis`' as well.

Try this first!

Answer (score 0):

You could try it with a **stream**.

```
    public static void persistAll(Context ctx, List<myObject> myObjects) {

    // save data to file
    FileOutputStream out = null;

    try {
           out = ctx.openFileOutput("file.obj",

           Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
           ObjectOutputStream objOut = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
           objOut.writeObject(myObjects);
           } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
           } finally {
           try {
               out.close();
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           } 
       }
   }
```

It is working fine for me like this. Saving as text shouldn't be that different, but I don't have a Java IDE to test here at work.
Hope this helps!